# proxmox image import creates an 50GB disk regardless of image size

Tags: zfs, disk-space-utilization, proxmox, disk-image

If I import a disk image for vm 101 from a raw image, it will create an 50GB disk image:

```
# qm importdisk 101  disk.img local-zfs
importing disk '446-jenkinsmite.img' to VM 101 ...
transferred 0.0 B of 50.0 GiB (0.00%)
transferred 512.0 MiB of 50.0 GiB (1.00%)
transferred 1.0 GiB of 50.0 GiB (2.00%)
transferred 1.5 GiB of 50.0 GiB (3.00%)
...
transferred 49.9 GiB of 50.0 GiB (99.76%)
transferred 50.0 GiB of 50.0 GiB (100.00%)
transferred 50.0 GiB of 50.0 GiB (100.00%)
Successfully imported disk as 'unused0:local-zfs:vm-101-disk-0'
```

The command

```
qm create 101 --scsi0 local-zfs:0,import-from=/root/disk.img,size=13G
```

still creates an 50GiB disk.

I realise, that the image does not (yet) take up 50GB, it should behave like a sparse file:

```
# zfs list rpool/data/vm-101-disk-0
NAME                       USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool/data/vm-101-disk-0  12.2G  2.50T     12.2G  -
```

However, the VM will see the disk size as 50GB, and if it has some cloud guest tools installed, it will resize partitions and the file system to use up the available space, and in time may use up that space.

I did not yet try to import a disk image larger that 50GiB, but that could also cause problems...

**How do I set the size of the target disk while importing an image?**

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround pretty fast. You can set the ZFS subvolume size by running something like:

```
zfs set volsize=1GiB rpool/data/vm-101-disk-0
```

### Be careful!

- If you set a size smaller than the original image, you WILL have data loss!
- If you mistype the volume name, you WILL have data loss!

There is no warning or asking if you are sure, so better calculate the size well and be sure that you are resizing the appropriate volume.

---

Also, proxmox still lists disk size as 50GiB:

```
# qm list
  VMID NAME                 STATUS     MEM(MB)    BOOTDISK(GB) PID       
   101 VM 101               running    512               50.00 2128896
```

I do not know if this leads to any unpleasant side effects (the VM seems to see the disk as the ZFS subvolume size), so I would be happy to have a better solution, preferably one that creates a subvolume with the appropriate size.